# using setup.py for finding packages under directory with different name that of package

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I have the following directory structure:

```
foo/
└── setup.py
└── src/
    └── bar.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Here I am trying to install the package `src` under the name `foo`.
My `setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foo',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages = find_packages(where='src'),
    package_dir = {'foo': 'src'},
    python_requires='>=3.8')
```

I installed the package using `pip install -e .` from the directory `foo`. When I try `import foo` or `import foo.bar`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError` but `import src` works. How do I modify `setup.py`, so that `import foo` works?

Some additional information:
here is my `__init__.py`:

```
from foo import bar
```

and `bar.py`

```
def bar():
  return "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

`setup.py` would need to be outside of the directory foo then modify `setup.py` to contain:

```
packages = ['foo'],
package_dir={'foo': 'foo/src'},
package_data={'foo': ['src/*']},
```

The import would then be `from foo import bar`and the use `bar.bar()`

Comment: Here, `foo` is the root directory. If I am not wrong, your solution suggests to create a `foo` directory on top of `foo` and place `setup.py` in it. But that's not I want and in any case, I don't want to reference `src` when importing module.

Comment: Edited the answer so that you will be able to accomplish what you require, only downside is to move `setup.py` to outside the foo package